# Do different versions of python handle indexing differently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, indexing

python 3.10.4
Ubuntu 20.04 running python 3.10.4
spyder IDE Python 3.9.12 64-bit | Qt 5.9.7 | PyQt5 5.9.2 | Linux 5.15.0-47-generic

My python version in ubuntu and spyder are different. Does this cause the following problems?

I've run into two separate incidents on two separate sites where my IDE produced a different output to the one i the example.

B) [This other website](https://www.askpython.com/python/list/indexing-in-python) states that the following code:

```
fruits = ["apple", "grape", "orange", "guava", "banana"]
 
#Printing out the indexes of Apples and Banana
print("Indedx of Apple: " + fruits.index("apple"))
print("Indedx of Banana: " + fruits.index("banana"))
```

will produce the output:
**Indedx of Apple: 0
Indedx of Banana: 4**

However, my IDE returns:

**TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str**

*I made an error with question A and have removed it*

Comment: I get `orl` for the first piece of code. What IDE gives you something different?

Comment: Run away from [this other website](https://www.askpython.com/python/list/indexing-in-python), that's totally wrong.

Comment: In B, your version of python is returning the correct result. The index is an int, and it's trying to join it with a string. You can cast it to a string using `str`. It's likely that they just didn't bother testing their code when they posted it. However, your result is incorrect in A.

Comment: If you're getting `Wor`, that suggests you're missing the ending `!`. The correct result is `orl` regardless of version.

Comment: You certainly didn't run this exact code in your first case, and couldn't get this exact output anyway (where has the capital 'W' gone?)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Wow, a site worse than GeeksForGeeks. On the "Previous Post": `#Getting the length of an array: array.len()` (where `array` is a list). That's embarrassingly bad.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yep... To their credit: the home page has an article titled "Top 10 Python Programming Homework Help Sites", and they didn't include SO ;)

Comment: Yes for A it was my error and I apologize for that.  @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, different versions of Python/IDEs/operation systems do not handle indexing differently.

For (A), please double check that you have not made some mistake when copying the code. For a start, it seems very unlikely that you are getting `wor` because `wor` is not even in the original string. Do you mean `Wor`? Is it possible that you missed the final `!`?

For (B), the website you copied from is wrong. Try the following:

```
fruits = ["apple", "grape", "orange", "guava", "banana"]

#Printing out the indexes of Apples and Banana
print("Indedx of Apple: " + str(fruits.index("apple")))
print("Indedx of Banana: " + str(fruits.index("banana")))
```